# Javascript fileobj.url returning absolute path when I want relative

Tags: javascript, relative-path, absolute-path, habari

I've begun bending Habari to my will, and just noticed that the javascript-driven image insert feature returns the absolute path by calling `fileobj.url` when building the HTML.

This is a bit of a problem when one wants to be able to run a blog mirror on a testbed, since my testbed image inserts are all sourced to `d:\websites\habari\...`

Is there an easy way to get `fileobj` to cough out a relative path rather than absolute?

*(found all sorts of questions about relative --> absolute, but none the other way!)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add Javascript to override `habari.media.output`. See the wiki page on [Adding Javascript and CSS](http://wiki.habariproject.org/en/Dev%3aAdding_Javascript_and_CSS), as well as the editor plugins, for example jwysiwyg, which do something similar. Then you should be able to remove the domain and path to Habari with a call to `Site::url('habari')` and some string munging.

Comment: Hi Michael. I recognize your name from the Dev Group. I assumed this was a JS-specific problem, rather than an issue with Habari, which is why I posted it here as I didn't want to clog up the Dev Group with non-Habari specific issues. :-)

Comment: No worries, I'll try to answer questions anywhere I can :)

Comment: You could (using jQuery, since it's already loaded in the admin) intercept the form submission on the publish page and rewrite links in the `content` textarea. The url you want to remove is already on the page too as `habari.url.habari`. Something like `$('#create-content').submit(function() {var text=$('#content');text.val(text.val().replace('foo','bar'));});` with an appropriate regex.